# what is If [[-n variable ]] syntax used for in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am fixing some old bash scripts I often see

```
if [[ -n $VARIABLE ]]; then
```

syntax I tried to google it but could find why "-n" is used for,
following is what I know

```
Comparisons:
  -eq   equal to
  -ne   not equal to
  -lt   less than
  -le   less than or equal to
  -gt   greater than
  -ge   greater than or equal to
```

File Operations:

```
  -s    file exists and is not empty
  -f    file exists and is not a directory
  -d    directory exists
  -x    file is executable
  -w    file is writable
  -r    file is readable
```

would anyone let me know what -n do ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`help test` would tell you:

```
String operators:

  ....

  -n STRING
     STRING      True if string is not empty.
```

Comment: many Thanks i am pretty new to scripting and even while googling i only searched for if syntax which didnt give me what i was looking for.

Comment: @NoviceCoder: That's because it's not `if` syntax.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Well, there is an `if` syntax: `if TEST-COMMANDS; then CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS; fi` See http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu That doesn't make it `if` syntax; it's an operator for the `test` (`[`) command.

Comment: @devnull Then the author(s) of [this tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) beat about the bush: "The most compact **syntax of the if** command is...". You can't know in which sources to trust today with so much information on the internet...

Comment: @RaduRădeanu This tutorial isn't the __official__ reference.  The official reference can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu You read the tutorial incorrectly. It doesn't state that `[ ... ]` is called "if syntax", it correctly calls those `TEST-COMMANDS` which is used as part of an `if`.

Comment: @devnull Same thing:see **3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs** ("*The syntax of the if command is...*"). Maybe is not official anymore...

Comment: @RaduRădeanu The `if` command takes a `test` command.  It's the `test` command (or `[`) that has the `-n` operator.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Nobody denies that there is "if syntax", but `test` is not "if syntax".

Comment: Ok, guys. I misunderstood: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said "*because it's not `if` syntax*" and I understood something like: "does not *exist* an `if` syntax". Sorry, I got carried away. Vote up!

Comment: The `if` statement in `bash` is broader than in most languages. Rather than take a boolean expression, it takes any command. The `test` command is the one used to implement boolean expressions.

Answer (score 4):

If `$VARIABLE` is a string, then `[ -n $VARIABLE ]` is true if the length of `$VARIABLE` is non-zero.

Also, `[ -n $VARIABLE ]` is equivalent with: `[ $VARIABLE ]`, when and only when `$VARIABLE` is a string.

More about: [Introduction to if](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)

Comment: The two are not equivalent (i.e. VARIABLE=0).

Comment: @cforbish That's not the case. I start my answer saying that "*If `$VARAIBLE` is a string*".

Comment: You started a new sentence and it is not clear in the new sentence you mean only if the variable is a string.  Consider an edit.

Comment: @cforbish no, `[ 0 ]` is true. `-n $var` is identical to `$var`, even the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test) says as much.

Answer (score 1):

The various *tests* that `[[ ... ]]` and `[ ... ]` use in `if` and `while` loops are from the Unix `test` command itself. An easy way to see what these various tests are is to look the [test](http://man.cx/test) manpage.

In Unix, the `/bin/[` command is actually a hard link to the `/bin/test` command. In early Unix systems, you would write this:

```
if test -n $parameter
then
    echo "Parameter has a value"
fi
```

or

```
if test $foo = $bar
then
    echo "Foo and Bar are equal"
fi
```

The `/bin/[` was created, so you could do this:

```
if [ -n $parameter ]
then
    echo "Parameter has a value"
fi
```

and this

```
if [ $foo = $bar ]
then
    echo "Foo and Bar are equal"
fi
```

This explains why the funny syntax and why you need a space between the square brackets and the parameters inside.

The `[[ ... ]]` is actually a <strike>Korn shellism</strike> ... I mean a POSIX shellism that BASH has <strike>taken</strike> *borrowed*. It was introduced to allow pattern matching tests (`[[ $foo == bar* ]]`) and is internal to the shell, so its less sensitive to shell command line expansion issues. For example:

```
if [ $foo = $bar ]
```

will fail if either `$foo` or `$bar` is not set while:

```
if [[ $foo = $bar ]]
```

will work even if one of those two variables aren't set.

The `[[ ... ]]` syntax takes all of the same testing parameters that `[ ... ]` does and is now preferred.

Comment: But nobody uses `[ ... ]` without quotes! so `[ "$foo" = "$bar" ]` will work even if one is not set... besides, it will work even if `foo` or `bar` contain spaces.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Everybody _should_ use quotes, or `[ x$foo = x$bar ]` (the last way prevented issues in Bourne shell when `$foo` started with a dash). However, people forget to use quotes, and the script works with the type of rough testing most people do with shell scripts before they're on a production system. It will work 99% of the time. That 1% of the time it will fail will happen at 2am during the time the system is most busy.